# Add a Node to a class that extends Scene

Tags: java, javafx

How can I add a custom pane to a custom scene in that code?

```
public class MainScene extends Scene {
  public MainScene() {
    super(new FlowPane(), 800, 600);
  }

  public void addItem(String name) {
    Item item = new Item(name); // Item extends Pane.
    getRoot().getChildren().add(item); // That obviously doesn't work.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you do not have a reference to the root element.

Without asking it from the user, you cannot pass the reference of the root element because of the use of `super()`.

Since `getRoot()` returns a Parent, you cannot use `getChildren()` on it for obvious reasons.

What you can do is to type-cast the `getRoot()` to `FlowPane`.

```
public void addItem(String name) {
    Pane item = new Pane(); // Item extends Pane.
    ((FlowPane)getRoot()).getChildren().add(item);
}
```

Comment: I know that, but `root` is private and `getRoot()` has only a `getChildrenUnmodifiable()` method.

Comment: Excellent ! Good idea, I haven't thought about that.